# Check for expiry of a cookie and trigger an action after it expired in react

Tags: javascript, cookies, reactjs

I am using `react-cookie` npm package to handle cookies in react. What I want to do is to check whether a cookie is present and if not, then redirect the user to a login page. However the cookie has an expiry of 30 min and I want to check for the expiry of the cookie and redirect the user to the login page again.

Currently I am performing this operation in `componentWillMount` lifecycle of react but if checks the condition only when I refresh the page. I know I should use the componentWillUpdate lifecycle of react and check the state but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my code.

```
componentWillMount() {

        let  getCookie = cookie.load('token');
        let exp = cookie.load('exp');
        console.log(getCookie);
        if(getCookie === undefined || ((exp - new Date().getTime()) < 0)) {
            let url = 'http://localhost:8080/login.html'
            window.location.href =  url
            console.log(url)
        } 

    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

As in JavaScript document.cookie. The cookie automatically expires after a set expiry time. Similarly `react-cookie` also has `opt expires` in it. Is there a way I can use this to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a timer with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) ?
something like

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  // check again for expire and redirect
}, cookie.load('exp') - new Date().getTime())
```

inside the `willMount` or `didMount` lifecycle

Comment: Will it work properly because new Date().getTime() changes every millisecond

Comment: you can assign the current date time to a variable, which capture the current time when the component being/did mount. Component mounting only happens once so the date will not changed